# Find the maximum volume of a box with an open top and when the surface area = A

Tags: calculus

I am a Calculus one student
There are a bunch of these questions about finding the maximum volume of a box on Stack Exchange.  I was looking at this question; [Finding dimensions of a rectangular box](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345913/finding-dimensions-of-a-rectangular-box#:%7E:text=Surface%20Area%20%3A%20%24%24xy%20%2B,2xz%20%2B%202yz%20%3D%20108%2Ccm%5E2%24%24)

I was looking at answer number two and trying to see if I could follow, and instead of $108 cm^2$ replace it with A.  The first equation I have to work on then is the surface area equation; $$A=xy+2xz+2yz$$ $$A=xy+2z(x+y)$$  $$z=\frac{A-xy}{2(x+y}$$

Then I can substitute the surface area constraint equation into the volume equation. $$Volume= xy \left(\frac{A-xy}{2(x+y)}\right)$$

Then I need to find $\frac{d}{dx} xy \left(\frac{A-xy}{2(x+y)}\right)$ and $\frac{d}{dy} xy \left(\frac{A-xy}{2(x+y)}\right)$

Here are the derivatives $$\frac{d}{dx} xy \left(\frac{A-xy}{2(x+y)}\right)=\frac{y^2(a-x^2-2xy)}{2(x^2+y^2+2xy)}$$ $$\frac{d}{dy} xy \left(\frac{A-xy}{2(x+y)}\right) = \frac{x^2(a-y^2-2xy)}{2(x^2+y^2+2xy)}$$

Then I set the derivative equal to zero for each equation.
The two equations I came up with are $$x=-\frac{-a+y^2}{2y}$$ $$y=-\frac{-a+x^2}{2x}$$

I am not really sure how to interpret this.  I was looking to find out if I am doing something wrong and if not what the next step would be.  It could be I plug these two equations into the constraint equation and find z.  But, at this point I am pretty turned around and was looking for some advice and help.  thank you

Comment: From your last two equations you can get $y=x$, then substituting back into either gives $3x^2=a$.  BTW I think your $A$ and $a$ should be the same, yes?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.